# ttest return values within by , sort: in Stata

Tags: static-analysis, stata

I have a data set with about 40 variables.  About half of these are measurements and the other half are demographical information about that observation.  Each id has two observations entry and exit.  I am comparing the means of the measurements at entry vs exits.

I have written the code to run ttest for each of the measurements and store then in a txt file and this works well.

Now I need to do some grouping by the demographic variables.

I am using the following

```
by var1, sort: ttest var2 by stage
```

stage is the variable that defines wether the observation is as entry or exit.
var1 is one of the demographic variables (ex gender, smoking, alcohol use) and can have 2-4 coded values.

What I am trying to do is run this code in a loop and write to a text file.  However, the r() commands only return the results of the last group that the ttest was run on.

The code it self it working as all the ttest results are printed to the results screen however, not all of the results are being written to the file.

For example if var1 has the possible values of 1 ,2 ,3 and 4 I am only getting the results for group 4.

```
foreach var of var  ttlchol-exvol{
foreach v of var sex dm chf diastolic copd ckd Depression {
        capture by `v',sort: ttest `var' , by(stage)
        if !_rc {
        by `v',sort: ttest `var', by(stage)
        file write myfile2 ///
            %9s "`var'" _tab %7.3f (r(N_1)) ///
            _tab %7.3f (r(N_2))      _tab %7.5f (r(p_l)) /// 
            _tab %7.5f (r(p_u))      _tab %7.5f (r(p)) /// 
            _tab %7.5f (r(se))      _tab %7.3f (r(t)) /// 
            _tab %7.3f (r(sd_1))      _tab %7.3f (r(sd_2)) /// 
            _tab %7.3f (r(mu_1))      _tab %7.3f (r(mu_2)) /// 
            _tab %7.3 (r(df_t)) ///
            _n
                }
                                                            }
                            }
```

I've looked for more details of how STATA handles the by , sort:  but I have not been able to find a way to capture the results for each iteration.

Is it possibly to obtain the results for each iteration of a by , sort: function?  If so how would I do this?

Comment: I would use `post` mechanics rather than meticulously fiddle with `file` operations, writing and then reading back. As an aside, DON'T YELL STATA, just say "Stata".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work, but I think it will help if you run each ttest individually, and then write the file after each ttest, rather than running the bysort which does up to 4 ttests at once. Here is my idea for doing this:

```
foreach var of var  ttlchol-exvol{
    foreach v of var sex dm chf diastolic copd ckd Depression {
        levelsof `v', local(coded_vals)
        foreach single_val of local coded_vals {
            capture ttest `var' if `v' == `single_val' , by(stage)
            if !_rc {
                ttest `var' if `v' == `single_val' , by(stage)
                file write myfile2 ///
                    %9s "`var', `v' = `single_val'" _tab %7.3f (r(N_1)) ///
                    _tab %7.3f (r(N_2))      _tab %7.5f (r(p_l)) /// 
                    _tab %7.5f (r(p_u))      _tab %7.5f (r(p)) /// 
                    _tab %7.5f (r(se))      _tab %7.3f (r(t)) /// 
                    _tab %7.3f (r(sd_1))      _tab %7.3f (r(sd_2)) /// 
                    _tab %7.3f (r(mu_1))      _tab %7.3f (r(mu_2)) /// 
                    _tab %7.3 (r(df_t)) ///
                    _n
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Here:

```
levelsof `v', local(coded_vals)
```

Creates a local `coded_vals` that has all of the values of `v` that occur. It then iterates through these values and does a single ttest for each one, and records it to the file. I'm not a text formatting wiz but I also added a line to your file writer that records which coded value of `v` this is for. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: With this data structure, multiple t tests are no longer the natural way even to compare means. ANOVA or a more general linear model is indicated.

Comment: @I agree about the ANOVA.  But client specially wants this.  I am planning on doing both and explaing why the ANOVA is correct